# How to import excel file in Oracle SQL live

Tags: oracle, import-from-excel

Unable to import data from CSV to Live SQL.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the CSV in a spreadsheet.
2. If the data is in columns `A`, `B` and `C` then in `D1` put in the formula:

   ```
   ="INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ("
   &A1&", "
   &"'"&SUBSTITUTE(B1, "'", "''")&"', "
   &"DATE '"&YEAR(C1)&"-"&MONTH(C1)&"-"&DAY(C1)&"'"
   &");"
   ```

   *(Adjust the data types as required, here it assumes number, string, date for the data types.)*
3. Copy-paste the formula from D1 down for all the rows.
4. Copy-paste the generated `INSERT` statements in the D column values from the spreadsheet into Live SQL.